# How to shuffle a List in Elm?

Tags: elm

Let's say I have a list containing the numbers 1 through 5. How would I write a function in Elm called `shuffleList` such that it takes a list of integers as an argument and returns a randomized version of the list?

E.g.,

```
shuffleList [1,2,3,4,5]
{-5,1,2,4,3-}
```

It is OK to hardcode the random seed

Comment: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mgold/Elm-Random-Sampling/2.0.3/Random-Array

Comment: The code example for this library does not work

Comment: http://tylerscode.com/2016/06/list-shuffle-elm/

Comment: Re: tylerscode.com/2016/06/list-shuffle-elm , this example is not copy-and-paste ready and I have not gotten it to work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want the [`shuffle`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/random-extra/latest/Random-List#shuffle) function from elm-community/random-extra. Example of using that on [Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/qvPZPDQWGTa1/2)

If you want to do this by hand though, given an initial [`Seed`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Random#Seed) you can do the following (this makes use of some functions from the [elm-community/list-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest/List-Extra) package)

```elm
import List.Extra exposing (getAt, removeAt)
import Random exposing (Seed, int, step)

shuffleList : Seed -> List a -> List a
shuffleList seed list =
    shuffleListHelper seed list []


shuffleListHelper : Seed -> List a -> List a -> List a
shuffleListHelper seed source result =
    if List.isEmpty source then
        result
    else
        let
            indexGenerator =
                int 0 ((List.length source) - 1)

            ( index, nextSeed ) =
                step indexGenerator seed

            valAtIndex =
                getAt index source

            sourceWithoutIndex =
                removeAt index source
        in
            case valAtIndex of
                Just val ->
                    shuffleListHelper nextSeed sourceWithoutIndex (val :: result)

                Nothing ->
                    Debug.crash "generated an index outside list"
```

An example using this on [Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/mNd3NhqpwV/1)